# No supported Swagger or OpenAPI version field for flask_swagger_ui

Tags: python, flask, coding-style, swagger, bdd

I use `flask_swagger_ui` to add "Swagger UI" to my application, but when I launched it I receive this error:

> > > Unable to render this definition The provided definition does not 
> > > specify a valid version field.
> > >
> > > Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field. Supported
> > > version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match  openapi: 3.0.n
> > > (for example, openapi: 3.0.0).

## swagger specific

```
SWAGGER_URL = '/swagger'
API_URL = '/static/swagger.json'
SWAGGER_UI_BLUEPRINT = get_swaggerui_blueprint(
   SWAGGER_URL,
   API_URL,
   config={
       'app_name': "my_application"
      }
    )
app.register_blueprint(SWAGGER_UI_BLUEPRINT, url_prefix=SWAGGER_URL)
```

## /static/swagger.json

```
{


"info": {
    "description": "this is swagger application",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "swagger-application",
    "contact": {
      "email": "me@gmail.com"
    },
    "license": {
      "name": "MIT",
      "url": "https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT"
    }
  },
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "paths": {}
}
```

## Solved

The problem comes from my browser (or else from the hidden memory of my browser), when I refresh it, it does not download the new modifications.
So to fix this problem follow this [wiki](https://fr.wikihow.com/actualiser-automatiquement-les-pages-web-sur-Chrome)